# NestJs - Graphql Error Cannot determine a GraphQL input type for the <Field>. Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I am currently developing a blog app using Nest, mongoDB and GraphQl by following this documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers and construct my DTO using mapped type https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/mapped-types..
But I encounter an error

```
Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL input type ("UserDTO") for the "author". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
    at InputTypeFactory.create
```

here is the `post.dto.ts` file

```
import {
  Field,
  InputType,
  IntersectionType,
  ObjectType,
  PartialType,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { BaseDTO } from 'src/shared/dto/base.dto';
import { PagedResultDTO } from 'src/shared/dto/pagedResult.dto';
import { UserDTO } from '../user/user.dto';

@ObjectType({ isAbstract: true })
export class PostBaseDTO {
  @Field()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  description: string;

  @Field()
  headerPhoto: string;

  @Field()
  content: string;

  @Field()
  komootId: string;

  @Field()
  date: Date;

  @Field(() => [String])
  keyword: string[];

  @Field(() => UserDTO, { nullable: true }) //THE ERROR IS HERE, when passing "UserDTO" as the type
  author?: UserDTO;
}

@ObjectType()
export class PostDTO extends IntersectionType(
  PostBaseDTO,
  BaseDTO,
  ObjectType,
) {}

@InputType()
export class CreatePostInputDTO extends IntersectionType(
  PostBaseDTO,
  BaseDTO,
  InputType,
) {}

@InputType()
export class UpdatePostInputDTO extends PartialType(PostDTO, InputType) {}

@ObjectType()
export class PostsPagedResultDTO extends PagedResultDTO<PostDTO> {
  @Field(() => [PostDTO])
  public records: PostDTO[];
}
```

and `user.dto.ts` file

```
import {
  Field,
  InputType,
  IntersectionType,
  ObjectType,
  OmitType,
  PartialType,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UserRole } from 'src/schemas/userRole.schema';
import { BaseDTO } from 'src/shared/dto/base.dto';
import { PagedResultDTO } from 'src/shared/dto/pagedResult.dto';

@ObjectType({ isAbstract: true })
export class UserBaseDTO {
  @Field()
  public email: string;

  @Field()
  public username: string;

  @Field()
  public password: string;

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  public role: UserRole;
}

@ObjectType()
export class UserDTO extends IntersectionType(
  UserBaseDTO,
  BaseDTO,
  ObjectType,
) {}

@InputType()
export class CreateUserInputDTO extends OmitType(
  UserBaseDTO,
  ['role'] as const, 
  InputType,
) {}

@InputType()
export class UpdateUserInputDTO extends PartialType(UserDTO, InputType) {}

@ObjectType()
export class UsersPagedResultDTO extends PagedResultDTO<UserDTO> {
  @Field(() => [UserDTO])
  public records: UserDTO[];
}
```

---

then I tried to implement this in `user.dto.ts` file

```
@InputType()
export class UserDTOInput extends IntersectionType(
  UserBaseDTO,
  BaseDTO,
  InputType,
) {}
```

and pass it as the the `author` type in `post.dto.ts`, but still throwing an error...

any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally fixed it. I put the relation field, in this case `author` field in `PostDTO` (ObjectType) and  `CreatePostInputDTO` (inputType) with different type

```
@ObjectType()
export class PostBaseDTO {
  @Field()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  description: string;

  @Field()
  headerPhoto: string;

  @Field()
  content: string;

  @Field()
  komootId: string;

  @Field()
  date: Date;

  @Field(() => [String])
  keyword: string[];
}

@ObjectType()
export class PostDTO extends IntersectionType(
  PostBaseDTO,
  BaseDTO,
  ObjectType,
) {
  @Field(() => UserDTO, { nullable: true })
  author?: UserDTO; //will be called via resolveField
}

@InputType()
export class CreatePostInputDTO extends IntersectionType(
  PostBaseDTO,
  BaseDTO,
  InputType,
) {
  @Field(() => String) // to store the objectID string
  author: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId
}
```

But still, I am not sure if this approach is good or not. For now at least, it is working :D